# How to structure a simple Wordpress project in Agile Scrum Team

Tags: scrum, agile, jira

We have a projects for example a brochure website for a client to be built on wordpress, its 6 pages. Lets say we already have the design and to make it a finished thing it requires aa mix of frontend and backend developers to deliver the project.

We have every unique layout designed for each page. In an agile scrum environment whats the best way to task this would you create a user story for each design

"as a user I can view and interact with the homepage as per the 'homepage design'"

then a front end person might create tasks under this story

create the framework for the navigation
create the jscript to manage the slider

a backend would add stories like

integreate into Wordpress' menu system the main navigation etc.

-OR-

would we treat each design as an epic which would be 'make the frontpage' and the stories would be along the lines of

front end wise
As a user I can interact with the main navigation (as in the visual) so I can browse different pages
As a user the slider needs to be able to move left to right after 3 seconds so as to present a different message *

- this would involve a front end and a back end person would this then get sub tasked?

Suggestions appreciated

Comment: First, fix your user stories and INVEST in them. They sound very much like *requirements* instead of stories. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/INVEST_(mnemonic)

Comment: Related answers: http://pm.stackexchange.com/a/16314/4271, http://pm.stackexchange.com/a/16885/4271.

Comment: Related site searches: [UI user stories](https://pm.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Buser-stories%5D+ui) and [web user stories](https://pm.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Buser-stories%5D+web).

Answer (score 1):

A [user story](https://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/agile/user-stories) describes something that a user wants to do and why they want to do it. A common format for user stories is:

> As a *who* I want to *what* so that *why*

An example of this:

> As a website user I want to view a list of articles on cooking in time-sorted order so that I can see the latest stories first

The story does not contain any implementation or design details. For example, it would not mention a slider, a carousel or any other web component.

The *why* is important as it gives the development team context and so can guide them on their implementation.

The *who* is also important. For example, some stories could mention first-time users of the website and other stories could mention experienced users of the website. Different users may have different needs from the site.

The development team discusses these user stories as a part of sprint planning. They may then break each story down in to a number of *technical tasks*. These tasks will contain implementation details and will cover all that is needed to actually do the work.

Why do we do this? A user story is intended to be understood not just by the development team but also by the end users. There is a clear separation between the user story, which is user-focused and the tasks, which are implementation-focused.

Comment: Thanks, so in terms of my example i would write all the user stories in relation to each layout and group them together in a way that will determine when the overall page is done?

Comment: Remember that a page on your site is an implementation detail. As an end user I would be interested in some functionality (say, finding out about chicken recipes). I don't care if it is on one page or two pages, I only care about the recipes. So write your stories focuses on what the user wants. Then it is up to the team to decide how those stories get implemented. They may take a group of stories and say "let's do these stories together and that will result in a complete home page for the site". That's up to the development team as it is an *implementation* detail and not a requirement.